# Problem with dual monitor setup after resume

Tags: display

I am running a desktop pc with dual monitors. I have a 34" UltraWide as my primary monitor and a 32" monitor (extended to the right). I am also using a GTX1080 and both displays are connected through DisplayPort.
 The problem I have is that when i resume the monitors from sleep (only primary monitor is blank, the secondary still shows the desktop) I have to reconfigure again to have the secondary monitor "extend to the right". I have it set to "Configure new displays when connected". Otherwise it is a hassle to get into the display function to configure the displays. I have also saved the settings for the displays from the Nvidia X Server Settings to /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.
 I have the XFCE Power Manager set to Blank after 20 minutes and Switch off after 25 minutes (system is set to never hibernate).

Hopefully someone can assist in figuring this out. It is not a show stopper for this distribution... it is just annoying.

Thank You 
Kevin